# How to populate Bitmap object with pixels from pngcs?

Tags: c#, png, transform

Pixels are stored in PNG sequentally (in 2 variants - raw and Adam-interlaced). There is RFC 2083, which describe these variants of layouts. I want to understand how to convert pixel positions in stream into positions in bitmap.

There are some obstacles - the sequential number depend on the dimensions of image (in interlaced mode some pixels can be skipped, because they are out of bounds).

How to implement this clearly, or does ready-made implementation exist?

Comment: What are you trying to do? if you're trying to read directly a png file it's not pixel data, it's compressed and encoded, after decomrpessing and decoding you will get the pixel data, and all of that can be done automatically for you just using Image.FromFile...

Comment: https://github.com/leonbloy/pngcs/issues/12

Comment: You're messing mixing things, the class you pointed in the help does nothing like reading a png, it takes an *already loaded* png and manipulates it. Again, reading a PNG is not a matter of just reading pixel data, it's LZH compressed and RLE encoded, better take a managed premade class instead of doing it by yourself, something like pngcs which returns already the pixel data

Comment: i am asking exactly about how to use pixels from pngcs for drawing on bitmap

Comment: pngcs will solve for me all problems you describe above. All I need is to fill Bitmap object with these pixels

Comment: that's because default implementation of Bitmap constructor have a bug in unsafe native libpng library (or in libgdiplus), and I want to replace them with managed version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using pngcs as you stated you will receive an array of integers representing the pixel data without the need to care about interleaving.

Then it's easy, look at the example at https://github.com/leonbloy/pngcs/blob/master/SamplesTests/SampleTileImage.cs, each X integers is a pixel, X is defined by the channel quantity, so each integer is a component of a pixel, which means each line has [components * imageWidth] integers.

To reconstruct the data then a double for loop will be enough, here is an example for a PNG of four components (RGBA):

```
int componentSize = 4;
int lineSize = componentSize * imageWidth;
int linesOnImage = imageData.Length / lineSize;

for(int y = 0; y < linesOnImage; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
    {
        int startPixel = y * lineSize + (x * componentSize);
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(imageData[startPixel + 3], imageData[startPixel], imageData[startPixel + 1], imageData[startPixel + 2]);
        //Do whatever you need to do with the pixel, you have X and Y coordinates and the color
    }
}
```

Note the first param for the color is the last component of the pixel as Color expects ARGB input and PNG uses RGBA order.